# Cannot resolve symbol 'IndoorCloudManager' Estimote SDK

Tags: java, android, estimote

Recently i am trying to build my own android application using Estimote SDK and i'm following this [Tutorial](http://developer.estimote.com/indoor/android-tutorial/). I'm getting an error on IndoorCloudManager.

```
IndoorCloudManager cloudManager = new 
IndoorCloudManagerFactory().create(applicationContext, new 
EstimoteCloudCredentials("YOUR-APP-ID", "YOUR-APP-TOKEN"));
cloudManager.getLocation("my-kitchen", new CloudCallback<Location>() {
@Override
public void success(Location location) {
    // store the Location object for later,
    // you will need it to initialize the IndoorLocationManager!
    //
    // you can also pass it to IndoorLocationView to display a map:
    // indoorView = (IndoorLocationView) findViewById(R.id.indoor_view);
    // indoorView.setLocation(location);
}

@Override
public void failure(EstimoteCloudException e) {
    // oops!
}
});
```

Comment: You are probably missing `import` statements.  (The tutorial you are following doesn't mention details like that.  My guess is that it is aimed at people with Android / Java developer skills.)

Comment: @StephenC Do you have any idea what is the import statement used to import this class? i've tried this `import com.estimote.cloud_plugin.*` but nothing changed.

Comment: `compile 'com.estimote:indoorsdk:2.0.0'
   compile 'com.estimote:sdk:1.3.0'`

Comment: See https://estimote.github.io/Android-Indoor-SDK/docs/index.html.